# Mercurial: Getting changed files from revision?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg

I can't get my head around how I can get only the files that were changed in my last revision, and not the complete repo, which i get by using Clone. This would  be super helpful to for instance, deploy the last changed files.

What do I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Martin has the right way to get a list of what files have changed in a revision, and I've upvoted his answer, but just to expand on why your question is a little off:

In Mercurial every location has a full copy with all changes.  If you're going to use Mercurial to deploy to your server then you have to clone everything to your server -- once.  After that push/pull will move over only the (compressed) changesets that the server doesn't already have.

If you don't want to have everything that ever was on the server, then you need to use something other than mercurial for your deployment, perhaps something fed from the status commands Martin showed or a snapshot created from `hg archive`.

Personally, I'm okay with having full history on my servers, and just do a `hg pull ; hg update` on the server for each new deployment.  It's tidy and efficient.

Comment: Hi Ry4an - I am well aware of Mercurial needs a full copy with the changes. I won't be able to run mercurial on all servers where code lies, so I will need to use FTP/SSH to upload files, and it is be quite nice to just upload the files that have changed. I tried the archive thing which seems to work really well, especially within the Repo browser in Tortoisehg. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You cannot transfer just some files -- you must always have a full clone locally. So I suggest you make that once and then pull in changes incrementally.

You should then use `hg status` to show the names of files changes been revisions. You normally use `hg status` to see which files are changes compared to the working copy parent revision, but you can pass `--rev` to status to see changes between any two revisions!

So use

```
$ hg status --change tip
```

to see which files were changed in the tip changeset. Use

```
 $ hg pull
 $ hg status --rev .:tip
```

to see what files will be changed when you do a `hg update` after a pull. The update will take you from the current working directory parent, denoted by `.`, to the `tip`, assuming you are on the same named branch as `tip`. Otherwise `hg update` will take you to the tip-most changeset on your current branch.

Comment: Also `--change REV   list the changed files of a revision`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a template to `hg log` or `hg tip` to get all filenames:

```
hg tip --template '{files}'
```

or to get e.g. all files changed/added/modified by changeset 5:

```
 hg log -r5  --template '{files}'
```

You can read more about templates [Mercurial: The Definitive Guide, Chapter 11. Customizing the output of Mercurial](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/customizing-the-output-of-mercurial.html) or short help with hg help templating`

If you want to do something to the files e.g grep through them:

```
hg tip --template '{files}' | xargs grep foo
```

Careful this will break with filenames containing spaces!

To process all kinds of filenames something more complicated is needed (thanks to mg on #mercurial for the tip):

We need multiline styles for this suppose a file named `zerosep` contains:

```
changeset = "{files}"
file = "{file}\0"
```

Then you can use this to produce a `\0` separated list of filenames and process it with `xargs -0`:

```
hg tip --style zerosep | xargs -0 grep foo
```

Information how this works can be found in: [Listing files on multiple lines](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/customizing-the-output-of-mercurial.html#id417978)

Comment: `hg help status` shows `-0 --print0   end filenames with NUL, for use with xargs`.